Filtering subjects based on having sample at specific time points
I have a dataframe with multiple samples collected from different individuals looking like



ID
Subject
Week




ID01
S01
Week_2


ID02
S01
Week_4


ID03
S01
Week_5


ID04
S02
Week_3


ID05
S03
Week_2


ID06
S03
Week_4


ID07
S04
Week_1


ID08
S04
Week_4


ID09
S04
Week_5



I want to filter out the subjects and samples without both Week_4 and Week_5 collection time points using dplyr to have



ID
Subject
Week




ID01
S01
Week_2


ID02
S01
Week_4


ID03
S01
Week_5


ID07
S04
Week_1


ID08
S04
Week_4


ID09
S04
Week_5



at the end.

You may do this with all in filter for each Subject :
library(dplyr)
keep_week <- c("Week_4", "Week_5")

df %>% filter(all(keep_week %in% Week), .by = Subject)

#    ID Subject   Week
#1 ID01     S01 Week_2
#2 ID02     S01 Week_4
#3 ID03     S01 Week_5
#4 ID07     S04 Week_1
#5 ID08     S04 Week_4
#6 ID09     S04 Week_5


Worked. Thank you
